# XPath Scraping Issue

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to use xpath to get structured information from a nutrition website. The problem is the category of information and the actual information, both of which I need, are on the same level. I was wondering if it possible to collect and organize the data in an array (as shown below). I have tried for a while now with no success.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Current Code:

```
            $query = "//a/@href | //h4/text()";
            $nodes = $xpath->query($query);
            $info = array();

            foreach($nodes as $node){           
                $info[] = $node->textContent;
            }
```

HTML

```
<h4>Fruits</h4>
<ul>
   <a href="link1">Apples</a>
   <a href="link2">Peaches</a>
   <a href="link3">Pears</a>
</ul>
<h4>Veggies</h4>
<ul>
   <a href="link4">Tomato</a>
   <a href="link5">Onion</a>
   <a href="link6">Mushroom</a>
</ul>
<h4>Junkfood</h4>
<ul>
   <a href="link7">Pizza</a>
   <a href="link8">Cola</a>
   <a href="link9">Hotdog</a>
</ul>
```

Desired Output:

```
$info = array(
               "fruits" => array("apples", "peaches", "pears"), 
               "veggies" => array("tomato", "onion", "mushroom"),
               "junkfood" => array("pizza", "cola", "hotdog")
             );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
 $query = "//a | //h4";

 $nodes = $xpath->query($query);

 foreach($nodes as $node)
 {
    if($node->nodeName == 'h4')
            $arraykey = $node->nodeValue;
    else
            $info[$arraykey][] = $node->nodeValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to go about this:

### A) Query all the elements of interest as a flat list, and then manually aggregate them based on their node name

Code:

```php
$info = array();
foreach( $xpath->query("//h4 | //a") as $el ) {
    if ( $el->nodeName == "h4" )
        $category = $el->textContent;
    elseif ( isset($category) )
        $info[$category][] = $el->textContent;
}
```

### B) First Query just the 'h4' elements, then loop over them and query the corresponding 'a' elements for each one

The difficulty, in this case, is choosing the correct "second query".

- If you are sure that the `h4` and `ul` elements always alternate like that in the XML document with no exceptions, you can just use `./following-sibling::ul[1]/a`.
- If you are sure that the `ul` elements always *directly* follow the corresponding `h4` elements, you can use `./following-sibling::*[1][name()='ul']/a`.
- If neither of those things are guaranteed, it will become difficult (or even impossible) to encode in XPath, and I would use solution A instead in that case.

Code:

```php
$info = array();
foreach( $xpath->query("//h4") as $category ) {
    foreach ( $xpath->query("./following-sibling::ul[1]/a", $category) as $food ) {
        $info[$category->textContent][] = $food->textContent;
    }
}
```